# Postgres lose xlog

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 instances master-salve postgres run on AWS, the xlog folder is on ephemeral disk. The master instance was down, so I lose the xlog folder, Now, i'm trying to start up the master again and received messages :

- invalid primary checkpoint record
- invalid secondary checkpoint record
- PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record

Can anyone help me force start the master up, or any way to recover the xlog folder (from slave...etc).

Answer (score 2):

Putting `pg_xlog` on ephemeral storage was not a good move. Don't do that. Ever.

You can probably recover most of the data with `pg_resetxlog`, but you there's a high chance of things like duplicates in unique constraints or primary keys, missing foreign key referenced entities, deleted rows re-appearing, both the old and new copies of updated rows appearing, etc.

You should immediately attempt to `pg_dump` the database(s), then move the damaged data directory aside as an archive, `initdb` a new one, and restore the database - possibly after manual repairs.

Note: `pg_resetxlog` can seriously damage a database and should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks Craig, 
I tried to use pg_resetxlog -f data/folder but I got the same error.
The data is near 3T so it doesn't make sense to dump it.
The slave instance still run well, do you think we have other solutions ?

Comment: @HùngTrần Promote the replica and re create the master as a replica. Really, once you lose the xlogs your database is corrupt and cannot be used.